# What's the difference between mysqli::$affected_rows and mysqli_stmt::$affected_rows?

Tags: php, mysqli

Obviously, `mysqli_stmt::$affected_rows` is not available unless prepared statements are being used. But when prepared statements *are* being used, what's the difference between `mysqli::$affected_rows` and `mysqli_stmt::$affected_rows`?

I have the same question in regards to `mysqli::$insert_id` vs `mysqli_stmt::$insert_id`.

I'm trying to decide if I should be using one in favour of the other.

I've read the PHP manual entries for these properties. I've done some testing (PHP 5.3.17) using a single execute and using multiple executes. I don't see a difference.

So I am wondering if maybe there is some difference under certain circumstances (or certain versions). If they are exactly the same, why have both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysqli_stmt::$affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php):

> Returns the total number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the
>   last executed statement

[`mysqli::$affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php):

> Gets the number of affected rows in a previous MySQL operation

So, if the mysqli_stmt object was the last executed statement, both queries should give the same result.

Comment: Ah, yes. And conversely, if the mysqli_stmt object was *not* the last executed statement, they could be different.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only reason to keep `mysqli:$affected_rows` is `mysqli::query` and `mysqli::multi_query`, because they both don't use prepared statements. And the only reason to keep `mysqli_stmt:$affected_rows` is OOP: to encapsulate query related information in statement object.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered a difference between `mysqli_stmt::$affected_rows` and `mysqli::$affected_rows` that I didn't expect.

I assumed that `mysqli::$affected_rows` could be called after closing the statement because I expected it to report based on the last query executed on the *connection*. I didn't think it would matter if the statement was closed. However, it does seem to make a difference.

**This code:**

```
$db_err_msg = 'Database Error: Failed to update profile';
$sql = "UPDATE tblProfiles SET lngPhoneNumber = ? WHERE lngProfileId = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or output_error($db_err_msg);

$phone = 5555555555;
$id = 10773;
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $phone, $id) or output_error($db_err_msg);
$stmt->execute() or output_error($db_err_msg);

if ($mysqli->warning_count) {
    $warnings = $mysqli->get_warnings();
    do {
        trigger_error('Database Warning (' . $warnings->errno . '): '
            . $warnings->message, E_USER_WARNING);
    } while ( $warnings->next() );
}
else {
    echo 'no warnings', "\n\n";
}

echo 'Before $stmt->close()', "\n";
echo '$mysqli->affected_rows is ', $mysqli->affected_rows, "\n";
echo '$stmt->affected_rows is ', $stmt->affected_rows, "\n";
echo '$mysqli->affected_rows is ', $mysqli->affected_rows, "\n";

$stmt->close();
echo "\n", 'After $stmt->close()', "\n";
echo '$mysqli->affected_rows is ', $mysqli->affected_rows, "\n";
```

**produces this output:**

> no warnings
>
> Before $stmt->close()
> $mysqli->affected_rows is 1
> $stmt->affected_rows is 1
> $mysqli->affected_rows is 1
>
> After $stmt->close()
> $mysqli->affected_rows is -1

Note how the final value is negative 1.

**The PHP manual for `mysqli::$affected_rows` says:**

> -1 indicates that the query returned an error

The query updated the record as expected and did not return an error or warning. Yet this implies there was an error. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but it was certainly not what I expected. Regardless of which one you use, clearly the safest approach is to check it right after the execute statement.